# Double click run interval indefinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an `animation` using series of images. When someone `clicks` a button it `iterate` images with some interval & stops on `condition` current image number by `clearInterval`. Issue is when someone `clicks` in series on the buttons iteration becomes UN-stoppable and runs indefinitely. `clearInterval` won't works then.

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/LP35e/3/) as well.

Please help me fix this and let me know if I am not clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your relevant code within the question in addition to the jsfiddle.

Comment: since `loop` is global, once you call `walkfunc` again, all previous intervals that were defined are permanently unstoppable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to call `clearInterval` before you call `setInterval` again.  Otherwise you are overwriting the interval ID of the first call and will never clear it.

Alternatively, you can keep track of whether or not an interval is still going and only create a new one if the previous has finished.  Perhaps set `loop` to `-1` when you call `clearInterval` and only call `setInterval` if `loop` is `-1`.